# Laptop clicking sound when torrenting

Tags: hard-drive

My new laptop emits clicking sound every 5 seconds when downloading files:
https://voca.ro/7SbEQR32BOv

Should I worry about this sound and maybe start warranty claim or do more research instead with some HDD health utility checkers?

Comment: If its a spinning hard drive this is normal for it to make some low level noise, torrenting causes a lot of read writes to the hard drive.

Comment: @Moab it's not the noise that I'm concerned of, it's about those clicks. Noise that you heard is coming from the cooling system, but I'm afraid that this clicking sounds signal about near death of an HDD.

Comment: @tnsaturday That might very well be. What does the SMART status of your HDD say?

Comment: clicking is noise? some hard drives click when under heavy I/O load and torrenting will do this.

Comment: @Moab Please listen to the record again. It's pretty loud and yes, I do consider such sound as noise.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell how loud that noise is.
If it is very loud, the hard drive may have problems moving the reading head.
If it is loud, I would contact the support.
Or, as you said, check it out with an HDD monitor first.
A quiet click is normal, because when downloading and uploading data, the head must move a lot.

Comment: It's about as loud as a common wall clock. So, yes, it's pretty loud.

Comment: If that was my laptop I would definitely check the SMART status, and also backup my important data. I had a 2.5" disk that made that noise, and it failed soon after.